# SAP UI5 value help only for Smartfield

Tags: sapui5

I have a *smartfield* that has a `value-list` annotation. 
I would like it to behave such that text input is disabled for the field so the user is forced to open the value help when he clicks on the field, and select from a valid list - much like the `valueHelpOnly` property of `sap.m.Input`. I was looking for a similar property for `smartfield` but there isn't seem to be one?

If there's no standard property for this, what's the best way to validate input vs valid value help values for `smartfields`?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You can add the `disabled` property in the input

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following steps. Assume you defined the `SmartField` like this:

```xml
<smartField:SmartField value="{XXX}" textInEditModeSource="ValueList" innerControlsCreated="onControlCreated">
    <smartField:configuration>
        <smartField:Configuration preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false" displayBehaviour="idAndDescription"/>
    </smartField:configuration>
</smartField:SmartField>
```

Of course you have defined the needed annotation that shows the value list itesm. Something like this:

```xml
<Annotations Target="Metadata.YourEntityName/XXX">
    <Annotation Term="Common.Text" Path="Planttxt">
        <Annotation Term="UI.TextArrangement" EnumMember="UI.TextArrangementType/TextLast"/>
    </Annotation>
    <Annotation Term="Common.ValueListWithFixedValues" Bool="false"/>
    <Annotation Term="Common.ValueList">
        <Record>
            <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath" String="XxxSet"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
                <Collection>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterInOut">
                        <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="XXX"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Id"/>
                    </Record>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly">
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Name"/>
                    </Record>
                </Collection>
            </PropertyValue>
        </Record>
    </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

We defined a `innerControlsCreated="onControlCreated"` handler, we need to provide the code for that in related controller:

```js
/** 
* event fired by innerControlsCreated of SmartField
* @param {sap.ui.base.Event} oEvent pattern match event
*/
onControlCreated: function (oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getParameters()[0] instanceof sap.m.Input && oEvent.getParameters()[0].getShowValueHelp()) {
        // set ValueHelpOnly for Inputs with ValueHelp
        oEvent.getParameters()[0].setValueHelpOnly(true);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around, if any one has a better solution then kindly suggest me

- Add a `class` to you `SmartField` and using the `class` get the `ID` and add `disabled` attribute to the `SmartField input` tag

`var sSmrtFldId = "#" + jQuery(".CustomSmrtFldClass").attr("id") + ".sapMInputBaseInner";
 jQuery(sSmrtFldId).attr("disabled ", true);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Event `innerControlsCreated` of SmartField, then check if is a Input and call the method `setValueHelpOnly(true)`

```
onInnerControlsCreated: function (oEvent){
   oEvent.getParameters()[0].setValueHelpOnly(true);
}
```

Note: This code is a sample, you need to check if is a `Input` and avoid hard code the index access on the array of parameters.